# Template argument deduction with common ancestor

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following code doesn't compile.

```
class A {};
class B: public A {};
class C: public A {};

template<typename T>
void do_op(T in, T out) {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    B b;
    C c;
    do_op(b, c);
}
```

My question is, why templates do not deduce that there is common ancestor ?

Comment: Why do you think they should?

Comment: Templates don't do implicit conversions in general. It's the same situation as `do_op(5, 2.5)`.

Comment: *Assuming* its did. The objects would be sliced on account of you passing by value. What use would there be then?

Comment: That would be way to complex and most likely wouldn't give you what you want.  For instance in Qt everything derives from QObject so if you have 2 very different classes eventually you would hit Qobject for both and the code would compile but most likely it would not do what you want.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo `b` and `c` are `A`. If both were converted to `A` the template I think should be valid.

Comment: @perencia: not if `b` and `c` had some data members.

Comment: Alright then pass it `do_op<A>(b, c);`

Comment: C++ does give you a work around: `template<typename T, typename U> void do_op(T in, U out) {}` and now you can decide if you want a `T` or `U`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I don't see why having data members changes the fact that they are both `A`.

Comment: @perencia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why templates do not deduce that there is common ancestor ?

They were simply not designed with that it mind - it would introduce significant additional complexity and make it easier to write incorrect code *(e.g. object slicing)*. The behavior you noticed is also consistent with the fact that template argument deduction doesn't take *implicit conversions* into account.

You can *(and IMHO, should)* take two different template parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void do_op(T in, U out) {}
```

Or, if you really know what you're doing...

```
do_op<A>(b, c);
```

Comment: And if you don't *really* know what you are doing, at least passing the template argument explicitly stands out.

Answer (score 1):

Templates deduce the types they are given, fitting the patterns provided (const, volatile, refs, ptr, etc).  They do not convert a T to an A for the same reason they do not convert ints to longs or chars to bools.

If you want do_op() to take and operate on base class references, they why not write it to take base class references:

```
void do_op(A const & in, A & out) { ... }
```